# задача по программированию hibernate+PostgreSQL с использованием маппинга. Ошибка not-null property references a null or transient value :

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, mapping

Студент-заочник в 53 года. Бьюсь неделю над последней лабой. Башка квадратная:)
Идея-ЕЕ. При запуске билд проходит, прога вылетает с ошибкой: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : hibernate.Album._albums_artist_idBackref at org.ssau.Main.main(Main.java:81). При этом в связанной БД таблицы создаются, но новые данные не заносятся...
Прилагаю исходные коды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

листинг cfg.xml:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- PostgreSQL connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/musicshop</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">***</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

    <!-- Other hibernate settings -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping package="hibernate"/>
    <mapping class="hibernate.Artist"/>
    <mapping class="hibernate.Album"/>
    <mapping class="hibernate.Tracks"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

<!-- end snippet ---------------------------------------------------------------------->

Листинг Main

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Где собака порылась? помогите...уже голос отчаяния...дедлайн на днях. Препод молчит как рыба об лед.

Comment: почему то не вставились другие листинги...вот они:

Comment: Скорее всего трабл в том, что при сохранении Album, одно из его полей на котором висит чек NOT NULL, приходит NULL, или оно еще не сохранено в бд.

Comment: Проблема в порядке сохранения сущностей. В вопросе первым сохраняется альбом, при этом у него должна быть ссылка на артиста с существующим ид. А т.к. артист еще не сохранен, то у него id = null, и происходит ошибка сохранения (insert в БД с указанным полем в ошибке). Нужно поменять порядок сохранения сущностей: сначала сохранить артиста, а потом альбом.